# How to make a QTextEdit fill its parent dialog?

Tags: qt, layout, qtextedit, qdialog

I've been using Qt for some times, but I'm quite new to layouts. I would like to create a dialog with a QTextEdit inside, and the QTextEdit would resize to fill the whole dialog. How can I use layouts to do that? Or is there some other technique that I'm missing?

I have tried adding a layout to the dialog, then put the QTextEdit inside. However, I cannot find any property to make the layout fit the whole dialog.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and explain how it's not working.

Comment: A toplevelt layout fills the whole widget its attached to, and there can only be one toplevel layout. Please post the relevant snippet of your code (probably the dialog constructor is enough).

Comment: I'm doing the dialog in the design view so I don't have a constructor to show. How can I create a toplevel layout in the design view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding the text edit to your form, right click on the form and you will see a "Lay out" menu item at the bottom of the context menu, select that and then the layout type you want to use. The designer will create a top level layout of that type for your form and the text edit should now expand to fill the form.

Comment: Thanks, that's the detail I was missing.